# UICollectionView: Reordering cells of varying, but fixed widths

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview, ios9

I am trying to build a UICollectionView that consists of cells that are of fixed height and varying widths. The cells can either be 100%, 50%, or 25% in width.

I am creating these cells from a custom subclass, and then I am adjusting the size in `sizeForIndexPath`. My problem is that when reordering cells, I get a lot of weird visual glitches as the cells have their sizes adjusted rapidly as the index path changes.

Basically, I want the size of the cell to depend on the type of cell (or the content in the cell), not the index path of the cell.

What is the best way to handle this? I thought about using multiple classes for the different types of cells, but I can't set the width of the cell with a frame when initializing it. Any ideas?

**Update: Here's a link to a video showing the bug I am trying to solve**

http://d.pr/v/FTM8+

Answer (score -1):

Try [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/63089/cookbook-moving-table-view-cells-with-a-long-press-gesture) tutorial. It for a table view but in the conclusion some recomendations for a collection view. I cannot try this tutorial now and garaunted it works for collection view but tomorrow I will do it.
Cheers.